# Monadic way to get first Right to result from getting an Either from items of a list?

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension

Up front: I know how to just write a custom function that will do this, but I swear there's a built-in thing whose name I'm just forgetting, to handle it in an idiomatic way. (Also, in my actual use case I'm likely to be using more complex monads involving state and assorted nonsense, and I feel like the answer I'm looking for will handle those as well, while the hand-coded one would need to be updated.)

I have a list `items : List[A]` and a function `f : (A) -> Either[Error, B]`. I vaguely recall there's an easy dedicated function that will apply `f` to each item in `items` and then return the first `Right(b)` to result, without applying `f` to the remaining items (or return `Left[error]` of the last error, if nothing succeeds.)

For example, if you had `f(items(0))` result in  `Left("random error")`, `f(items(1))` result in `Right("Find this one!")`, and `f(items(2))` result in `launchTheNukes(); Right("Uh oh.")`, then the return should be `Right("Find this one!")` and no nukes should be launched.

It's sort of like what's happening in a for comprehension, where you could do:

```
for{
   res0 <- f(items(0))
   res1 <- f(items(1))
   res2 <- f(items(2))
} yield res2
```

Which would return either the first error or the final result - so I want that, but to handle an arbitrary list rather than hard-coded, and returning the first success, not the first error. (The answer I'm looking for might be two functions, one to swap the sides of an `Either`, and one to automatically chain `foldLeft`s across a list... I think there's a single-step solution though.)

Code snippet for commented solution:

```
def tester(i : Int) : Either[String, Int] = {if (i % 2 == 0) Right(100 / (4 - i)) else Left(i.toString)}
(1 to 5).collectFirst(tester)
```

Comment: You may use `collectFirst` to get the first `Right` but no the last `Left`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I may be missing something - I tried that, and got `Some(Left(1))`, when I was hoping for `Right(50)`. (See the code I edited into my question)

Comment: What is the desired result if all of the `f(item(_))` are `Left`?

Comment: The last `Left` seems reasonable, or that could be a required argument. I don't mind if I get it wrapped - `Some(Right(50))` would be fine, though I suspect that's not in line with the pattern I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming (from your mention of more complex monads such as State) that you're using the Cats library.

You probably want one of the methods that come from [`Traverse`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html)

For example, its `sequence` and `traverse` methods are two variations of the "I have a list of things, and a thing-to-monad function, and I want a monad of things". Since Either is a monad whose `flatMap` aborts early upon encountering a Left, you could `.swap` your Eithers so that the `flatMap` aborts early upon encountering a `Right`, and then `.swap` the result back at the end.

```scala
def tester(i : Int): Either[String, Int] = /* from your question */
val items = (1 to 5).toList

items.traverse(tester(_).swap).swap // Right(50)

val allLeft = List(Left("oh no"), Left("uh oh"))
allLeft.traverse(_.swap).swap // Left(List("oh no", "uh oh"))
```

Comment: ZIO, actually, but close

Comment: And apparently the ZIO version of `traverse` is called `forEach`, which is the missing piece I was looking for (combined with `.flip`, which is the ZIO version of `.swap`)

Answer (score 0):

Ho about `list.iterator.map(f).collectFirst { case Right(x) =>x }` (this returns `Option(x)` of the first `Right(x)` it finds ... Could return `Option(Right(x))` but that seems redundant.

Or you might go back to either:

```
   list.iterator.map(f).collectFirst { case x@Right(_) => x }.getOrElse(Left("oops"))
```

If you insist on getting the last `Left` in case there are no `Rights` (doesn't seem to be very meaningful actually), then it seems like a simple recursive scan (that you said you knew how to write) is the best option.